# Can interconnect be resolved in to struct type?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification

I am getting error in elaboration of below sv code, Can interconnect resolved to struct?

```
 struct {
    byte a;
    reg b;
    shortint unsigned c;
  } myLocalStruct;

module top;
    interconnect n;
    structData sD(n);
endmodule

module structData( myLocalStruct x);

  initial begin
    $display ("a = %b b = %b c = %h", x.a, x.b, x.c);
    $display ("a = %b b = %b c = %h", x.a, 
         x.b, x.c);
     #1  $finish;
   end
 endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your code.

- `MylocalStruct` needs to be a `typedef`, not a variable
- As a wire, `MylocalStruct` must contain only 4-state types. So change

  - `byte` to `logic signed [7:0]
  - `shortint unsigned` to `logic [15:0]`

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use interconnect with the struct type. However to declare the struct as a port type you need to use `typedef` (as in Daves reply).

Also, the point of `interconnect` is to provide a type-less connection between modules, so it makes no sense to use it in a single module.

From lrm 6.6.8:

> A net or port declared as interconnect (an interconnect net or port) indicates a typeless or generic net.
>   Such nets or ports are only able to express net port and terminal connections and shall not be used in any
>   procedural context nor in any continuous or procedural continuous assignments. An interconnect net or
>   port shall not be used in any expression other than a net_lvalue expression in which all nets or ports in the
>   expression are also interconnect nets. An interconnect array shall be considered valid even if different bits in the array are resolved to different net types as demonstrated in the following example.

There are several examples in the standard, here is yet another simple example of use the interconnect with structs:

```
package is_pkg;
   typedef struct {
      bit         a,b,c;
   } S;
endpackage:is_pkg

module top();
   interconnect  bus;

   tb tb(bus);
   dut dut(bus);

endmodule // top

module tb import is_pkg::*; (output S so);
   initial
     so = '{0,1,1};
endmodule // tb

module dut import is_pkg::*; (input S si);
   always @*
     $display("struct: %b%b%b", si.a, si.b, si.c);

endmodule // dut
```

Answer (score -1):

System Verilog LRM 1800-2017 says following for port connection rule.

> It shall be illegal to connect a port variable to an **interconnect** port or **interconnect** net.

Comment: if you declare a port as interconnect, you cannot assign any variable to it and vice versa. has nothing to do with the question.